# NEC computer won't boot from USB - I have tried everything I can think of

Tags: linux, boot, bios, livecd, liveusb

System hangs after 'Verifying DMI Pool Data.......Update Success"

I have tried:

- Set boot priority (USB boot supported)
- Reset BIOS
- Search for BIOS update - none available
- Booting from CD - this works
- USB flash drive is recognised by BIOS as USB-ZIP
- Re-doing the boot USB with YUMI and Rufus

  - With Rufus tried MBR for BIOS or UEFI, MBR for UEFI and GPT for UEFI

This is an older NEC system; likely not UEFI. Any wisdom is helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Obviously, the computer model would help